# Lenevo P50 - Connecting external monitor through HDMI, OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, display, hdmi, display-resolution, external-monitor

I have a new Lenovo P50 workstation, OS - Ubuntu 14.04.

I am trying to connect Samsung SyncMaster 22 inch LED monitor through HDMI port.

Lenovo P50 laptop can recognize the monitor but display on the monitor is sluggish, the graphic seems to be a problem.

Here is the image of the graphic drivers -

[image]

The system is currently using Nouveau display driver, I have tried switching to NVIDIA binary driver - version 384. But it didn't produce any difference - the graphics on the external monitor is still sluggish.

Anyone else having the same problem? Should I just remove and reinstall the NVIDIA drivers? any other trick to resolve this?

Update:
There seems to be a known issue with ThinkPad P50 and HDMI port.
[External HDMI video does not function correctly - ThinkPad P50](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/sf16-t0051)

Comment: Does disconnecting and reconnecting HDMI cable after boot have any impact? Please [edit] that information as well as the output of  `uname -a` to your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 3):

I used to have this machine, and I encountered a similar problem. Often the external monitor would be slow and occasionally had trouble connecting after hibernation. I updated the kernel(i was not getting automatic updates) and then these problems were magically solved.

I am guessing that you do not want to update to a newer Ubuntu version but you might want to double check you have the latest kernel for 14.04.

How to update kernels:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus

Comment: however I believe that if possible you should try to upgrade ubuntu to a newer version

Comment: yes, I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and everything just worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to get an updated nvidia driver, it might be why the updated distro helps with the lag. http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your issue might be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1697395) and/or [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/intel/+bug/1717431) I don't have your hardware available for testing, but if my suspicions are correct, it appears that you'll want to upgrade to kernel v 4.14 or later in order to resolve this problem. Successfully built headers and images are available [here.](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/) Having [a backup](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) is highly recommended in case something goes wrong. And of course you can always just [boot a previous kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) and be no worse off than before.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers have a high chance of fixing the graphics for larger display.

However, I had to upgrade the OS to Ubuntu 18.04 and everything just worked out of the box. No graphics issues with larger display.